# Golang Parse Output to Read a Key (terraform output)

Tags: json, go, terraform, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have been trying to parse terraform output for terratest assertions

The output from running terratest is

```
 result := `[{
    "id": "/addressPools/test-pool"
    "name" : "test-pool"
 }]`
```

Note there is no comma after the **id** and the **name** fields (hence the output ain't a JSON)

Here is what I have tried so far with no success,

```
    type BackendAddressPool struct {
        ID   string `json:"id"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }

    func main () {
        result := `[{
            "id": "/addressPools/test-pool"
            "name" : "test-pool"
        }]`

        var backendAddressPoolData []BackendAddressPool
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(result), &backendAddressPoolData)
        fmt.Println(backendAddressPoolData)
        // outputs -> []
    }
```

I want is to read the output values like *backendAddressPoolData.Name* & *backendAddressPoolData.Id*

If I add a comma after the id field in the result, the code works fine.

See my complete code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ChVZ1MsI1zy)

Comment: the error from `json.Unmarshal()` is `invalid character '"' after object key:value pair`, which makes sense since you're trying to decode malformed JSON. I don't know anything about terratest, but if their API is supposed to be providing JSON, you might want to file an issue with them regarding the malformed JSON.

Answer (score 1):

try this  https://play.golang.org/p/pH8t2XXBF0W

```
func main() {
    result := `[{
            "id": "/addressPools/test-pool"
            "name" : "test-pool"
        }]`
    result = strings.ReplaceAll(result, "\n", "")
    result = strings.ReplaceAll(result, " ", "")
    result = strings.ReplaceAll(result, `""`, `","`)
    fmt.Println(result)
    var backendAddressPoolData []BackendAddressPool
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(result), &backendAddressPoolData)
    fmt.Println(backendAddressPoolData)
}

type BackendAddressPool struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```